# Analyzing the Impact of Mean Subtraction on Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics, statistical-inference, means, standard-deviation

I have two random series, $X$ and $Y$, and I've defined a third series $Z$ as:

$Z = X - Y$

Now, I want to compare two other series, $Y1$ and $Y2$, to understand why $Y1$ is generally closer to $Y$ than $Y2$. $Y1$ and $Y2$ are defined as:

$Y1 = X - 2 \cdot \text{mean}(Z)$

$Y2 = X - \text{mean}(Z)$

I'm looking to explain why, under certain conditions or assumptions, $Y1$ tends to be closer to $Y$ than $Y2$ in terms of values. I need a mathematical explanation for this observation.

Thank you.

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Comment: What do you mean by "generally closer"?  Could you give an example of $Y1$ closer to $Y$ than $Y2$? Note $E[Y1]=2E[Y]-E[X]$ while $E[Y2]=E[Y]$

Comment: Yes $X$ and $Y$ are independent. For computing the closeness, the metric of MSE error between $Y$, $Y1$ and $Y2$ is used. Also, the values of $X$ and $Y$ are signed.